# Rails: bootstrap-datetimepicker - How to show default value on cell?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have added bootstrap-datetimepicker gem to my application ( https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails ) which is the gem package of the original bootstrap-datetimepicker javascript module (https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker).

Although, backend populates initial datetime value in the form, the input field is empty when the page render complete. datetimepicker module runs as expected (ie: popup for date & time selector opens). When I remove the datetime trigger script code from the page initial value is displayed on the webform as expected.

Following is the erb template code snippet:

```
  <div class="field editor-datetime">
    <%= f.label :auction_finish %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :auction_finish %>
  </div>
```

This is the page html code rendered on the client PC:

```
<div class="field editor-datetime">
    <label for="car_ad_auction_finish">Auction finish</label><br>
    <input type="text" value="2018-06-23 00:54:00 +0300" name="car_ad[auction_finish]" id="car_ad_auction_finish">
  </div>
```

Following is the datetimepicker script on the page template. As you can see I have also tried to populate default time via an option which didn't work. Do you have any idea what might be wrong???

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#car_ad_auction_finish').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: "<%= @car_ad.auction_finish ? @car_ad.auction_finish.to_time.iso8601 : nil %>",
        locale: 'tr'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide a sample js fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, managed to set the default value in the cell directly on the text_field tag :

```
<%= f.text_field :auction_finish,
          value: l(@car_ad.auction_finish, format: :datetime_picker) %>
<!-- l() is short for I18n.localize -->
```

The thing to make it work is that the format of your date needs to be the same as the specified format in :

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'fr',
        format: "DD-MM-YYYY H:mm"
    });
```

For my case it was 'fr' locale, so I set in my config/locales/fr.yml :

```
time:
    am: am
    formats:
      default: "%d %B %Y %Hh %M"
      long: "%A %d %B %Y %Hh%M"
      short: "%d %b %Hh%M"
      datetime_picker: "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"
```